# TCPDF: Remove the Border Lines

Tags: tcpdf

I need some help urengtly please.

I am using TCPDF to create a label.

When the label is created, there are left, right, bottom and top borders lines around the page.

I would like to remove these border lines.

Would would this be possible?

Appreciate the help.

P.S: I did setMargins(-1,-1,-1,true) but that didnot help.

Thanks

Comment: You will need to post your code (or at least a cut-down version of your code that contains the calls to TCPDF) in order for us to help you with this problem.

Comment: I figured it out. It was because of the lines being added in my code.